# In the mass spectrum of niacin (3-pyridine-carboxylic acid), what ion corresponds to the peak at m/z = 105?

Tags: organic-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

The mass spectrum can be found [here](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C59676&Mask=200#Mass-Spec).

I am interested to know what ion this is and why the peak at $m/z = 105$ is higher than the peak at $m/z = 106$ (which I believe corresponds to $\ce{C5H4NCO+}$).

Answer (score 2):

From the general interpretation of electron ionization mass spectra, it would seem logical to report the $m/z$ 105 ion as a loss of $\ce{H_{2}O}$, thus $\ce{[C_{6}H_{3}NO]^{\bullet +}}$. As correctly suggested in the question, the peak at $m/z$ 106 is likely arising from a loss of $\ce{OH^{\bullet}}$ through an $\alpha$-cleavage of the $\ce{C-O}$ bond.

So the issue is: why would niacin (or nicotinic acid) undergo this $\ce{H_{2}O}$ loss? It is not observed for other similar molecules such as benzoic acid, which starts by a $\ce{OH^{\bullet}}$ loss. I did find two relevant publications in the literature on this point. Neeter and Nibbering<sup>[1]</sup> performed $\ce{D}$ labelling experiments, showing that the transferred hydrogen atom originates mostly from the $\alpha$ position (*ortho* from both the carboxylic acid and the nitrogen atom). Opitz<sup>[2]</sup> measured the appearance energy (AE) for $m/z$ 105 at 10.94 eV, more than 0.6 eV lower than the AE for $m/z$ 106 at 11.58 eV. He also suggests, based on metastable dissociation data showing loss of CO to $m/z$ 77, two possible structures for the $m/z$ 105 ion. So to answer the question: (a) formation of the $m/z$ 105 ion is thermodynamically favored compared to the formation of the $m/z$ 106 ion.

Based on this (scarce) literature evidence, I would suggest, based on labelling experiments, that some proton transfer occurs between the $\alpha$ cycle hydrogen and the hydroxyl group. This exchange can either move back and forth, or lead to a loss of water through formation of a cyclic structure.

---

**References**

1. Neeter, R.; Nibbering, N. M. M. Mass spectrometry of pyridine compounds. II: Hydrogen exchange in the molecular ions of isonicotinic and nicotinic acid as a function of internal energy. *Org. Mass Spectrom.* **1971,** *5* (6), 735–742. [DOI: 10.1002/oms.1210050612](https://doi.org/10.1002/oms.1210050612).
2. Opitz, J. Electron-impact ionization of benzoic acid, nicotinic acid and their *n*-butyl esters: an approach to regioselective proton affinities derived from ionization and appearance energy data. *Int. J. Mass Spectrom.* **2007,** *265* (1), 1–14. [DOI: 10.1016/j.ijms.2007.04.014](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijms.2007.04.014).

Comment: Where the 7th carbon atom in $\ce{[C_{7}H_{3}NO]^{\bullet +}}$ appeared since niacin only has 6?

Comment: @andselisk : Just edited the formula, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I did quick simulation with [MMass](http://www.mmass.org/) (open source, available on Windows, MacOS, Linux) for the isotopic distribution in this region (`Tools` > `Mass Calculator`), and it looks like there are two $[\ce{M}-\ce{1e}]^+$ fragments:

$$
\begin{array}{rlr}
\hline
\text{avg.}~m/z & \text{Fragment} & \text{a.i.}\\
\hline
105.09 & \ce{C6H3NO+} & \approx45\%\\
106.10 & \ce{C6H4NO+} & \approx21\%\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

[image]

Addition of the signals from both fragments (blue and green colors) would give nearly ideal peaks distribution reflecting experimental data (red color).

*Technical note*: MMass can import ASCII data, but NIST provides EI-MS spectra in unsupported JCAMP-DX format. To convert JDX to TXT, I used [JDXview](http://merian.pch.univie.ac.at/~nhaider/cheminf/jdxview.html) (free, Windows only).

Comment: I admit that MS is probably not my favorite method of analysis, but it would be nice if the downvoter would explain the down-vote.